# Azure Pipelines: Conditional run of task groups

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

In Azure pipelines, I can conditionally run a specific task/job. However, if I have a Task group, I don't see any option to specify conditions on its execution.

The only way am able to do this is to create a new Job altogher which runs the task group and specify the conditinal expression in the Job.

This has drawback - Jobs are run on different agents. In this case, a new agent is created only to run that task group under a condition. This slows down the deployment

So - question is - how to conditinally execute a Task Group?

Thanks

Comment: you can only put conditions in the tasks within the TG, then send variables to the TG to determine if you to run the tasks or not

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - I thought about that, but then if the Task Group has huge number of tasks, i'll have to check for that variable/condition in each and every task within. Didn't seem a very elegant way of doing it

Comment: you're right but I don't think there is another solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops#before-you-create-a-task-group): Task conditions (such as "Run this task only when a previous task has failed" for a PowerShell Script task) can be configured in a task group and these settings are persisted with the task group.

If you want to custom task group level condition, It is not supported by azure devops for the time being.

I found a [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365689/task-group-custom-conditions-at-group-and-task-lev.html) on our UserVoice site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

**Update1**

As a workaround, We can define these tasks in the [yaml template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime) and then we can call different templates from a pipeline YAML depending on a condition.

Sample code:

```
parameters:
- name: experimentalTemplate
  displayName: 'Use experimental build process?'
  type: boolean
  default: false

steps:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.experimentalTemplate, true) }}:
    - template: experimental.yml
  - ${{ if not(eq(parameters.experimentalTemplate, true)) }}:
    - template: stable.yml
```

Comment: Its a shame such a basic thing is missing out. I have some big task groups used in various pipelines and differeing scenarios. To be able to control their execution is a basic ask, hopefully its provided soon.

Comment: Hi @sppc42, The suggestion ticket status is On Roadmap, It seems that azure devops product team has checked this feature, you can follow that ticket to get the latest news. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @sppc42, I have update the answer, please check it. We can not use condition in the task group level but we can call different templates via the condition, we could define these task in the yaml template file.

Comment: That's what I precisely ended up doing and it works